# rails 4 controller testing -- how does it know to select html from get :index?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am reading though the recommended rails book (agile-web-development-with-rails-4_p2_0.pdf) and have a quick question about the code below.

```
class StoreControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  test "should get index" do
    get :index
    assert_response :success
    assert_select '#columns #side a', minimum: 4
    assert_select '#main .entry', 3
    assert_select 'h3', 'Programming Ruby 1.9'
    assert_select '.price', /\$[,\d]+\.\d\d/
  end

end
```

When selling `get :index` method how do the assertion's know to use that data as parameters? Is there some sort of magic going on behind the scenes in ActionController::TestCase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the "get" or "post" methods in functional tests populates test-related variables. Assert-response, for example, looks at the variable `@response`, which contains the text of the server's response to a GET request in its entirety and which is populated each time you call `get` or `post` in a functional test.

Answer (score 2):

[`assert_select`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Assertions/SelectorAssertions/assert_select) under the covers does a call to [`response_from_page_or_css`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Assertions/SelectorAssertions/response_from_page_or_rjs)

which just accesses the class variable `@response` that is created after making the request, and calls `@response.body`, and tests against that.

Click the "Show Source" links on the apidock.com pages to see how it is implemented.